# How to write "expert(s)(')(s) guide"?

Tags: apostrophe

How to name a written guide which grants you expert knowledge about a certain topic (after reading it).

Is it an

- expert guide
- experts guide
- experts' guide
- expert's guide
- expert' guide
- experts's guide

---

Also knowing why that's the case would be nice.

(what would be other tags but apostrophe?)

Comment: In (1) the *guide* is the expert. (2) See [beginners guide](/q/5804/). (3) and (4) See [user's guide](/q/36657). (5) and (6) are simply wrong. You should have been shown the sidebar's "Related" questions when you posted this. Did you check any?

Comment: It wasn't listed there. Checked again, it was but not very high. Also I was not sure if the same rules apply to beginner and expert.

Comment: You're saying it's the guide that's expert, not its owner, so I'd call it "Expert Guide," "expert" describing the "guide."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sorry, I still don't know the correct answer. Both links only target (3 - experts') and (4 -expert's). Both links say each can work but (4 - expert's) would be the better case which you say is wrong. Also it's some other meaning than intended. The beginner's guide target one beginner at a time. My guide does not target an expert. It also target a beginner which want to become an expert.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman does this also work if the guide is not a person but just a written document? Can this be the expert too?

Comment: @Ghoti Sorry; I miscounted/mistyped. Each should be referenced exactly once in my first comment, now corrected.

Comment: "(Subject matter): Guide for becoming an expert" would be the most accurate title or subtitle. Don't be afraid to be precise at the expense of two or three words.

Comment: @user8356 the topic name already itself is very long. It would also need a verb as well. Something like "Guide for becoming an expert in finding a super special topic"

Comment: << Beginners guide >> and << experts guide >> with the plural-form attributive (in sound mimicking the traditional possessive forms) are becoming more commonly seen today. I don't see these even mentioned in the previous threads, though << working mens clubs >> and << childrens clothing departments >> have been addressed.